# Как переводить только собственные фразы в Django?

Tags: django

Создаю сайт-портфолио на джанго для изучения и захотел сделать возможность просматривать сайт на 3х языках(en,ru,uk). До того, как начал этим заниматься даты отображались на русском (http://cashik.pythonanywhere.com/) а теперь они всегда отображаются на английском какой бы я язык не выбрал. [image] Я понимаю, почему даты отображаются на английском(перевод названий месяцев и тд отсутствует в моем локальном файле), но я не хочу переводить все файлы (админку, dates.py и тд). Возможно, есть вариант сделать так, чтоб джанго смотрел фразу в локальном .po файле, а если не находит, то переводит стандартными средствами?

Comment: The formatting system is disabled by default. To enable it, it’s necessary to set USE_L10N = True in your settings file. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/formatting/

Comment: This option is enabled. But when you change the language to Russian data continues to be displayed in English. Probably, it is important to note that when switching to English date is displayed in the same language, but in a different format!

Comment: код settings.py, где и когда продолжает отображаться, этот код отвечает за локаль. Если перевод идет другим способом, используются шаблонные теги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему. Оказалось, что каким-то образом были полностью закомментарованы файлы django.po в директориях $PYTHONPATH/django/conf/locale/(ru и uk). Я просто нашел, как должны выглядеть [эти файлы](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/conf/locale) и заменил ими мои испорченные файлы.

Скорее всего, проблема получилось из-за того, что я баловался с командами makemessages и compilemessages.

Пока что все корректно работает для команд с параметрами

```
makemessages -l lang -e html

compilemessages -l lang
```